# How to print a statement based on date and time in php

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

I want to **print a string like "live" , "upcoming"  etc based on the date and time**

If the article date and time is equal to the current date and time it will print live

If the article date or time is in the past then show nothing

If the article date is in the future then show upcoming

Here is my script :

```
 /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
     /*Validating time to print live or upcoming etc*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/

if($article_date >= $today_date) {

    if($today_hours < $article_shours) {
        $status = "<p class='upcoming'>1Coming Soon</p>";
    }

    elseif(($today_hours >= $article_shours) && ($article_date == $today_date)) {
        if( ($today_hours >= $article_shours) && ($today_minutes >= $article_sminutes) ) {
               $status = "<p class='live'>2live</p>";
           } else {
               $status = "<p class='upcoming'>3Coming soon</p>";
           }
      if($today_minutes >= $article_sminutes) {
        $status = "<p class='live'>4live</p>";
      }
    } else {
        $status = "<p class='upcoming'>6Coming soon</p>";
    } 

} else {
    $status = "<p class='upcoming'>7Coming soon</p>";
}


if($article_date < $today_date) { // if the date is passed then do nothing
    if( $today_date > $article_end_date) {
      $status = "8";
   }
}

 /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
 /*Validating time to print live or upcoming etc ENDS here*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/
```

But there are still some problems as it is not working well

Comment: What is in `$article_date`, `$today_date` etc? Data and datatype

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what is not working

Comment: i have a table of articles having date and time then when i am showing the article on front end of my website i want that it show statement based on the current date and time if the $article_date is equals to to current date etc...

Comment: `$article_date` is the date of article from the database `$article_hours` `$article_minutes` is the hours/minutes from time with the article and `$article_date` `$today_hours` `$today_minutes` are the current date and time...